# Retrieving Child Queries When We Run JavaScript Based Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have requirement where I have many JavaScript Procedures , I have to find out Call to that Procedure run and what are child SQLs (Embedded SQLS inside Procedure)ran under the main call to Procedure.

Can we accomplish this using QUERY_HISTORY, If yes what are attributes that would be required to be considered for Main Procedure Run that links to its associated Child SQL Runs using Query_HISTORY  dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use QUERY_TAG, but you can't execute ALTER SESSION inside SP, so it does not work.

I don't see there is an easy way.

One hack I can think of is to tag the SP's query with its name, before calling the SP, like below:

```
alter session set QUERY_TAG = 'sp_test_2';
call sp_test_2();
alter session set QUERY_TAG = ''; -- reset it after calling the SP
```

Then the queries run inside the SP will be tagged to be sp_test_2.

Then using below query to find the parent and child:

```
with parent_sp as (
    select regexp_replace(query_text, 'call (.*)\\(.*', '\\1') as key, *
      from table(information_schema.query_history())
    where query_text ilike 'call%'
),
child_sp as (
    select QUERY_TAG as key, *
      from table(information_schema.query_history())
    where query_text not ilike 'call %'
)
select
  p.query_id, p.query_text, p.query_tag,
  c.query_id, c.query_text, c.query_tag
from parent_sp p
JOIN child_sp c
ON (
   p.key = c.key
   and p.start_time <= c.start_time
   and p.end_time >= c.end_time
);
```

Not a perfect solution, but it can work.

Comment: `I tried to use QUERY_TAG, but you can't execute ALTER SESSION inside SP...` You can if you specify `execute as caller` in the header. If you need to execute as owner, it won't work.