# Is there any inbuilt function or a quick way to fetch the underlying object names used in a stored procedure or function?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created multiple stored procedures with more than 1000+ lines of code, but missed to keep track of which tables from which schemas I have used in each of SPs.

Is there any inbuilt function of get all the objects used in each SP? If not, then what might be the easiest way to get those details?

Answer (score 1):

This might not give you everything you are looking for, but if you isolate a SP execution on a warehouse, then you can use the `ACCESS_HISTORY` to see which objects were read.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/access_history.html

This is a fairly new view for Snowflake and it does have some limitations, so it really depends on what your stored procedure is doing.  Maybe it gets you partially there.

Answer (score 1):

Since the code can be dynamic, there is no way to determine if a SP will access which tables under which schemas. For example, table name can be passed in as a parameter.

For checking past queries that were triggered by the SP, there is no directly method of associating parent SP with its child queries at the moment, please see post here:
[Retrieving Child Queries When We Run JavaScript Based Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69750088/retrieving-child-queries-when-we-run-javascript-based-procedure)

If you use the method in that post, then you can try to parse those child queries and extract tables used.

Mike's suggestion will work for tables in the SELECT query, but the tables accessed by DML operations will not be covered.